# How to set color_mode to RGBA using script?

Tags: rendering, scripting

I am trying to set my render to be alpha. i have the following code

```
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.render.alpha_mode = 'TRANSPARENT' 
bpy.context.scene.color_mode = 'RGBA'
```

where of the two first lines works fine, but im getting an error in the last one.
so how do i set the color_mode to RGBA, instead of RGB, using python script?

Answer (score 6):

To set the color mode to RGBA for the current scene, use:

```
 bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.color_mode ='RGBA'
```

`color_mode` is a member [ImageFormatSettings](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70a_release/bpy.types.ImageFormatSettings.html#bpy.types.ImageFormatSettings.color_mode), which is in turn a member of [RenderSettings](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70a_release/bpy.types.RenderSettings.html#bpy.types.RenderSettings.image_settings). The render settings of a scene are accessible via [Scene.render](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70a_release/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.render).

See here for an explanation how to find out the access path:
[Blender/Python API Reference Usage: examples of how to use the API reference docs](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_4/info_api_reference.html)