# save image as RGBA using python?

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, color

I'm using [`save()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Image.html#bpy.types.Image.save) and I want the save color to be RGBA but by default it's set to RGB

I tried `ImageFormatSetting.color_mode='RGBA'` from python tooltip and I also tried

```
 bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.color_mode ='RGBA'
```

from [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/9086/131649) answer, but neither seem to be working,
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technically isn't the right answer, more of a work around

I was using `bpy.data.images.new()` to create the image, all I had to do was add `alpha=True`

```
bpy.data.images.new("color_buffer_copy" , 32, 32, float_buffer=True,alpha=True)
```

so now whenever I did use [`save()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Image.html#bpy.types.Image.save) it would automatically set Color as `RGBA` and save it

[image]